# Form with invalid feedback outside wrapper. Input and submit button inside wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get my form to look as it does in the first two images. I used bootstrap, html5, css3. I tried using a wrapper (with a border) but the invalid feedback is included in the wrapper and the border extends down instead of staying just on the input and the submit button. I tried using the css grid with divs around the input, button, and invalid feedback, but the invalid feedback won't show/link to the input. I tried including the button in a span, making the span absolute and the wrapper relative, but the button even with margin 0 will not go past the input b/c of the span. I have included the basic structure of my form.
The first two images are what I want. The last two images are what I currently have.
Please accept my apologies if I'm asking this the wrong way; I'm new to programming and new to using stackoverflow for coding.
Thanks.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function() {
    'use strict'

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
      .forEach(function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
          }

          form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
      })
  })() <
  /script>
```

```css
/* Form */

.form-control {
  border-radius: 40px;
}


/* Button */

#button-addon2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="needs-validation form-inline" novalidate>
  <div class="input-group has-validation">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" aria-describedby="validationServerFeedback" required>

    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn" type="submit" id="button-addon2">
                  <img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow-img">
                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="validationServerFeedback">
      Please provide a valid email
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

[image: Form design]

[image: Invalid feedback]

[image: What I currently have]

[image: What I currently have showing the Invalid Feedback]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with the z-order of the button?  Here's some css that might get you started:

```
    .input-group{
        position: relative;
    }
    .form-control{
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: green;
        border-radius: 40px;
    }
    .btn{
        position: absolute;
        left: 260px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 55px;
        z-index: 2;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it pretty much works. Instead of .btn , I used .input-group-append. If I played with .btn, the button still remains outside the input when I position it. Also, I needed to toggle with the .input-group width and height instead of .form-control width and height. A few minor tweaks with the numbers, and it looks great. I just learned z-index in class today. Thanks for your help.